# add mysql query to virtuemart

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

I'm new to virtuemart.

While trying to add hits to virtuemart products
I create new filed in `"jjws5_virtuemart_products"` in database and called it `views`.

Then I added my PHP code to the place I need it to appear in.

> templates/mytemplate/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default.php:

```
<?php //views hits
    mysql_query("UPDATE jjws5_virtuemart_products SET views=views+1 WHERE virtuemart_product_id = '$virtuemart_product_id'");
    $views_hits = mysql_query("SELECT views FROM jjws5_virtuemart_products WHERE virtuemart_product_id = '$virtuemart_product_id'");
    while($total_views = mysql_fetch_array($$views_hits)){
        echo "Hits: ".$total_views['views'];
    }
?>
```

However, it's not showing anything.

What should I do to show it?

Comment: Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? This looks like it's got a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) in it. I hope you're not forced to use [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) with Virtuemart because that function was deleted in PHP7.

Comment: sorry i can't understand you
how to d this
it's my first programming in virtuemart or Joomla

Answer (score 0):

You use a variable variable to fetch result (maybe only a typo).

Change:

```
while($total_views = mysql_fetch_array($$views_hits))
```

in:

```
while($total_views = mysql_fetch_array($views_hits))
```

And, in the future, remember to activate error checking in our php code:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_error', 1 );
```

With error checking, our original code produce this error:

> PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in (...)

Comment: thanks i got and edit this but still not showing any thing

Comment: @MohamedMehanny So your query fails. 1) Have you activated error checking? If not, do it; 2) What is the content of `$virtuemart_product_id` ? Don't imagine it, print it to see if it is as expected; 3) Reproduce your query in phpMyAdmin to see if it works

Comment: yes i activate error checking from joomla administrator to development and also use your code but not showing any thing , $virtuemart_product_id is the primary key in "jjws5_virtuemart_products" table , this working in phpMyAdmin when define the "id" to any product

Comment: Not what is it, but **what is its content:** before your query, write `echo $virtuemart_product_id; die();` to see if it is as expected.

Comment: nothing happened also , i think virtuemart have specific way to work with it , i try to reach to this document but the document provide in the website is very poor and don't find useful thing in it

Comment: You are sure that your template is loaded?

Comment: i removed some element from my page and it's affected , but views never show anything